# Python class __init__ layout?

Tags: python, class, init

In python, is it bad form to write an `__init__` definition like:

```
class someFileType(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.filename = self.getFilename()
        self.client = self.getClient()
        self.date = self.getDate()
        self.title = self.getTitle()
        self.filetype = self.getFiletype()
    def getFilename(self):
        '''Returns entire file name without extension'''
        filename = os.path.basename(self.path)
        filename = os.path.splitext(filename)
        filename = filename[0]
        return filename
    def getClient(self):
        '''Returns client name associated with file'''
        client = self.filename.split()
        client = client[1] # Assuming filename is formatted "date client - docTitle"
        return client
```

where the initialized variables are calls to functions returning strings?  Or is it considered lazy coding?  It's mostly to save me from writing `something.filetype` as `something.getFiletype()` whenever I want to reference some aspect of the file.

This code is to sort files into folders by client, then by document type, and other manipulations based on data in the file name.

Comment: Totally fine. Even makes it easier to read.

Comment: Looks fine to me, unless one of your getFoo() functions happens to take a really long time, in which case you might want to defer it until it's actually required.

Comment: I would prefer a caching @property.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Care posting this is as an answer?

Comment: @freakish That's what the OP's code does.

Comment: @Kay That is a lot of added complexity. Unless it's proven to be needed, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Lattyware for this example it'd be needlessly complex. More generally I would say that it is easy enough to understand. A proper decorator would be reusable, too. (There will be dozens of c+p'able examples in the web.)

Comment: Precomputation, directly or through properties, is dangerous if the underlying values might change. (See my answer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, I don't see why that would be bad form. Calculating those values only once when the instance is created can be a great idea, in fact.

You could also postpone the calculations until needed by using caching `property`s:

```
class SomeFileType(object):
    _filename = None
    _client = None

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    @property
    def filename(self):
        if self._filename is None: 
            filename = os.path.basename(self.path)
            self._filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        return self._filename

    @property
    def client(self):
        '''Returns client name associated with file'''
        if self._client is None:
            client = self.filename.split()
            self._client = client[1] # Assuming filename is formatted "date client - docTitle"
        return self._client
```

Now, accessing `somefiletypeinstance.client` will trigger calculation of `self.filename` as needed, as well as cache the result of it's own calculation.

In this specific case, you may want to make `.path` a property as well; one with a setter that clears the cached values:

```
class SomeFileType(object):
    _filename = None
    _client = None

    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @path.setter
    def path(self, value):
        # clear all private instance attributes
        for key in [k for k in vars(self) if k[0] == '_']:
            delattr(self, key)
        self._path = value

    @property
    def filename(self):
        if self._filename is None: 
            filename = os.path.basename(self.path)
            self._filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        return self._filename

    @property
    def client(self):
        '''Returns client name associated with file'''
        if self._client is None:
            client = self.filename.split()
            self._client = client[1] # Assuming filename is formatted "date client - docTitle"
        return self._client
```

Because `property`-based caching does add some complexity overhead, you need to consider if it is really worth your while; for your specific, simple example, it probably is not. The calculation cost for your attributes is very low indeed, and unless you plan to create large quantities of these classes, the overhead of calculating the properties ahead of time is negligible, compared to the mental cost of having to maintain on-demand caching properties.

Comment: While this code certainly works, I think it would be even more clear if the _filename = None where moved into the __init__ method rather than remain a class attribute until overridden by the property.

Comment: @jlund3: Why? There is absolutely *no point* in doing that. You could perhaps remove the attribute altogether and use `if not hasattr(self, '_filename'):` instead of testing for `if self._filename is None:` but setting it to `None` in the initializer serves no purpose. `_filename` is not *overriden* by the property. The property is called `filename` without the underscore, and the property sets a instance attribute to cache the value. By making it a class attribute we simplify testing if the cache has been set yet, and *save space* otherwise.

Comment: +1 for the doing the `_filename = None` outside the `__init__` method. Never seen that particular idiom before. :)

Comment: @Aya: it's called a class attribute. Methods are really class attributes too; they are just attributes of the class that happen to resolve to a function object instead of another type.

Comment: Another interesting fact of this idiom is that you call use `del inst.member`, so it will return the "default value" again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh. I know exactly how it works - it all hinges on the fact that setting `self.foo` always hits `self.__dict__` even if there's a `foo` in `self.__class__.__dict__`. I just never saw class attributes used that way before. I only ever used them for 'static' members.

Comment: Yes, resetting the cache is as easy as calling `del inst._filename`.

Comment: I supposed the only downside is if `self.foo` is being referenced many times, it might be marginally slower if it's coming from `self.__class__.__dict__` than `self.__dict__`, but I guess the same applies to member functions.

Comment: @Aya: the lookup is done in C, I wouldn't worry too much about the speed differences there. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Must... save... one... nanosecond. ;-) Nah, you're probably right.

Comment: I am not saying that it is bad practice per se (this pattern is found all over the standard lib for example), but someone who is not familiar with the difference between class and instance attributes might be confused about what is happening when you first check if self._filename is None and then later set self._filename to some value.

Comment: If you change the line `self.path = path` to `self._path = path`. then you'll fix the consistency issue mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: @amcnabb: less of a inconsistency and more of a missing `property` that invalidates the caches.

Comment: @jlund3: No, `del self._filename` will *fail* if you didn't access `inst.filename` before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, you can also fix the inconsistency by adding a write method to the property to invalidate the cache.

Comment: @amcnabb: That is what I did; add a property for `cache` that invalidates the caches.

Comment: This works, of course, but should it be recommended as best practice? You future-proof by deleting _all_ computed values that begin with `_`, but what if another project member decides to add a protected variable for a different purpose? It'll mysteriously vanish whenever `path` is modified! Now you need a dedicated prefix (`_comp_` or whatever), or some other extra complexity. My point: It's complex and it's hard to get right, and then maintain.

Comment: @alexis: Sure, that is why I commented right above it what those two lines do. You *always* need to evaluate code you find on the internet and make sure you understand what it does, not blindly follow it. :-)

Comment: I've got no issues with the code (and I enjoyed the interplay of class and instance attributes :-)). The question is whether (and when?) this is best practice. In this example, the payload is not obviously constant and the computation being cached is cheap, so I suggested avoiding the trouble and complexity of caching. Your answer isn't giving me second thoughts yet...

Comment: @alexis: Sure, we are discussing options here, and in this specific case the calculations are very cheap indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is doing two different things:

a) Simplifying the class API by exposing certain computed attributes as variables, rather than functions.

b) Precomputing their values.

The first task is what properties are for; a straightforward use would make your code simpler, not more complex, and (equally important) would make the intent clearer:

```
class someFileType(object):
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.path)
```

You can then write `var.filename` and you will *dynamically* compute the filename from the path.

@Martijn's solution adds caching, which also takes care of part b (precomputation). In your example, at least, the calculations are cheap so I don't see any benefit in doing so.

On the contrary, caching or precomputation **raises consistency issues**. Consider the following snippet:

```
something = someFileType("/home/me/document.txt")
print something.filename    # prints `document`
...
something.path = "/home/me/document-v2.txt"
print something.filename   # STILL prints `document` if you cache values
```

What should the last statement print? If you cache your computations, **you will still get `document` instead of `document-v2`!** Unless you are **certain** that nobody will try to change the value of the basic variable, you need to either avoid caching, or take measures to ensure consistency. The easiest way is to prohibit modifications to `path`-- one of the things that properties are [designed to do.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

**Conclusion:** Use properties to simplify your interface. Don't cache computations, unless it's necessitated by performance reasons. If you cache, take measures to ensure consistency, e.g. by making the underlying value read-only.

PS. The issues are analogous to database normalization (non-normalized designs raise consistency issues), but in python you have more resources for keeping things in sync.

Comment: Just as a note: if the class is written properly, then an assignment to something.path would invalidate the cache'd filename and trigger a recalculation the next time it is requested.

Comment: Right, that's the alternative to prohibiting modifications altogether. But it requires either defining a setter for `path` (which would null all the computed values) or (for heavier applications) setting a flag or timestamp and checking it on each access to a computed value. More importantly, it requires time, thought and debugging to get it right. "If it's written properly" are the magic words.

Comment: Cached values normally do.

Comment: They do (or at least they should), I'm with you there. But @Martijn's much upvoted answer didn't. (It's example code, I know, but the bottom line was "this is a fine way to do it").

Comment: Agreed. There are plenty of uses for the "fetch once, return forever" school (a few Singleton patterns come to mind), but they can be very dangerous.